# How to forward declare a templated std::function

Tags: c++

How do I forward declare a std function that is templated so that it could be used with various types?

```
namespace std{
    template<typename R, typename T>
    class function;
}
```

and then else where

```
std::function<void(int)>
```

Doesn't seem to work.

**Edit**: Switched over to using boost::function. Still can't get it to compile.

Following the suggestions,I forward declare like this in my header:

```
namespace boost {
    template<typename R>
    class function;
}
```

and use like this again in the header:

```
boost::function<void(int)> mIdReceiver;
```

Then in my source/.cpp file I include `<boost/function.hpp>` and initialize the field.

And I get

> mIdReceiver uses undefined class boost::function<void(int)>

error.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Ignoring std issue, primary template is`template <class /*Sig*/> class function;`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work @Jarod42

Comment: Well now you're providing a forward declarations (for something you really shouldn't) and then trying to define an instance of it when only a declaration and no definition is available. The compiler error even tells you this. This is why you need to include the appropriate header so you have the definition available for use. You really should take a step back and get a better handle on what a declaration is and what a definition is and why the latter is needed here. Again I must ask, *why* do you *think* you *need* this?

Comment: forward declaration is not enough to use it like that...

Comment: ignoring std issue, it is still not clear why you think you would need this. Also for `boost::function` you include the header and thats it

Comment: This is the header. in my .cpp file I have the proper addition of the header that has the actual definition of boost::function. But I want to forward declare the type in the header and include boost in .cpp. @CaptainObvlious

Comment: Then you have to ensure that the definition is available before you try to define an instance of it. Are you sure the definition you have provided matches exactly that of the one in boost?

Comment: That's exactly my question. I can't tell exactly what boost uses for it's definition. There are a ton of macros and it's hard to tell what is going on. This is what they have: ```template<typename R BOOST_FUNCTION_COMMA
         BOOST_FUNCTION_TEMPLATE_PARMS>
class function<BOOST_FUNCTION_PARTIAL_SPEC>
  : public BOOST_FUNCTION_FUNCTION<R BOOST_FUNCTION_COMMA BOOST_FUNCTION_TEMPLATE_ARGS>```

Comment: @OmerOzer There will be a primary template declaration and (possibly many) partial/full specializations of that class template. You would need to forward declare all of them. The declarations will also likely depend on compile-time flags like the C++ version, because boost intents to support e.g. pre-C++11 where variadic template parameters weren't supported. That's probably what all these macros are for.

Comment: @OmerOzer: "*use like this again in the header:*" You cannot do that. This requires that the type be *defined*, not merely *declared*.

Comment: i think you should edit your post and include the exact minimal header and source file of what you are trying to accomplish. If you are trying to define an instance of `boost::function` or `std::function` and the definition is in fact **visible** to the compiler at that point that's one thing but if you are trying to **define it before the definition is available** then what you are doing is wrong, not supported by the language, and decoding all the boost macros isn't going to change a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to declare or define a (primary) class template in the `std` namespace in the first place. It will cause the program to have undefined behavior.

This is especially true if you try to do this for a name that is already part of the standard library as is `std::function`. It will immediately clash with `std::function`'s declaration.

It is surprising that you are trying to do that. There is no valid use case. If you need `std::function`, then you must `#include <functional>` and it will be declared properly without you needing to add anything to the `std` namespace manually.

Comment: ignoring the issue of std, how would I declare such a template? Say for boost::function instead.

Comment: @OmerOzer I don't really understand what your question is. Are you asking how `function` needs to be declared so that `function<void(int)>` works? That's just `template<typename> class function;`. `std::function` then has a partial specialization for function types and leaves the primary template undefined. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function.

Comment: Yes. I switched over to using boost to get around the issue with std. Followed your suggestion. Still doesn't compile. See the updated , question. @user17732522

Comment: @OmerOzer You shouldn't declare anything in the `boost` namespace either. It belongs to the library, not you. What is it you are trying to achieve? You only need to include `<boost/function.hpp>` in the header before you declare `mIdReceiver`.